# Including Participant ID in Event Registration Email

Tags: civievent, online-registration

I am attempting to include the Participant ID in the email sent to the participant upon successful event registration.  I have searched documentation and previous questions/answers, but no luck so far.  I was able to get the Participant ID on the Thank you Screen using info from a previous question -- involved changes to DisplayProfile.tpl  But it is not included in the confirmation email.  There were some older (2010/2011) questions that referenced using the email workflow templates, but they were not specific enough for me as to where to put the {ParticipantID} token.

Answer (score 6):

Susan, Welcome to CiviCRM stack exchange. Its possible to add Participant ID in email sent when a user registers online. You need to update the message template to include the `{$participantID}` token which prints the participant ID when rendered.

To update the message template navigate to CiviCRM >> Mailings >> Message Templates. Locate 'Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line)' under 'System Workflow Messages'. Click Edit. Modify the message template to include the `{$participantID}` token either in subject, html or text field.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Appreciate the quick response, and, yes that worked.   Had to get past a rusty old coder mistake...lower case p in participantID.

Comment: Can we close this as answered than?